# What is the 'ext' property of a JSON web key for?

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api, jwk

I'm generating and exporting a JSON web key (jwk) (see [RFC 7517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517)) using the browser [crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) with the following code (with thanks to [this excellent webCrypto examples page on GitHub](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#aes-ctr)):

```js
async function makeKey(){
  const key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    { name: "AES-CTR", length: 128 },
    false,
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
  )
  return window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("jwk", key)
}
```

What I get back is a JSON object with a number of properties, very similar to the one in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey#JSON_Web_Key), looking something like this:

```js
{
  alg: "A256CTR",
  ext: true,
  k: "...", //the actual key, a random string of characters
  key_ops: undefined,
  kty: "oct"
}
```

All of the above properties are defined in the RFC linked above, except for `ext`.  I've looked through a number of sources (including but not only MDN and the RFC) and I cannot seem to find a definition.  While all works fine just leaving it as defined above, I'd much rather (particularly for something like `crypto`) know what everything is there for.  So, what is the purpose of the `ext` property of a jwk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a reference to this in the [w3 webCrypto API documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI).

It is an extension to the jwk specification.  Section 15 on the JsonWebKey dictionary has the following definition:

```js
dictionary JsonWebKey {
  // The following fields are defined in Section 3.1 of JSON Web Key
  DOMString kty;
  DOMString use;
  sequence<DOMString> key_ops;
  DOMString alg;

  // The following fields are defined in JSON Web Key Parameters Registration
  boolean ext;

  // The following fields are defined in Section 6 of JSON Web Algorithms
  DOMString crv;
  DOMString x;
  DOMString y;
  DOMString d;
  DOMString n;
  DOMString e;
  DOMString p;
  DOMString q;
  DOMString dp;
  DOMString dq;
  DOMString qi;
  sequence<RsaOtherPrimesInfo> oth;
  DOMString k;
};
```

Which leads to the section on [JSON Web Key Parameters Registration](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#iana-section-jwk) which defines it as being short for `extractable` which, from the context of the rest of the document, indicates if the key can be exported.

Given that the jwt was generated by exporting it this will always be `true` for any key thus generated, however setting it to `false` before importing a key would prevent it from being re-exported.